# How Spring Cloud relates to Docker Swarm

Tags: spring, docker, cloud, spring-cloud, docker-swarm

I'm confused with cloud/clustering technologies like Docker Swarm and Spring Cloud and how they relates to each other.

Is it correct way to thing, they implement *same* functionality at different layers? For example docker swarm performs load balancing and service discovery at *container* or *network* layer (application is agnostic of this layer), where as framework like Spring Cloud embeds this logic to application, giving more flexibility, but also violating separation of concerns.

Am I mistaken, or is this correct? What is the SWOT of each approach, and is there any reason to use both Docker tooling and Spring Cloud utilities together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, Spring and Docker are two different technologies coming from different points of view. From what I can gather, Spring Cloud is a mechanism for deploying java containers and orchestrating them.

Docker is an application / OS agnostic deployment mechanism.

I don't know much about Spring Cloud, but if you're in an environment that is not all Java, it may make more sense to approach Docker. It would allow you to deploy micro services on just about any platform.

We went through this at the last company I worked for, as they were implementing Springboot, but also looking at Docker at the same time. In the end it just made sense to deploy everything in Docker since it provided a uniform deployment and service management mechanism. That as opposed to hobbling together various deployment and management tools by language.